# Maintaining constant bar height of horizontal bar chart irrespective on number of bars

Tags: excel, vba, charts, height

I'm using VBA to create horizontal bar charts. The number bars in the charts is defined at runtime. I want to maintain a constant bar height across charts with a different number of bars. I've only found that I can manipulate the `.GapWidth` and `.Height` of the chart and am currently adjusting `.Height` to maintain a constant height.

I'm currently doing this math to calculate the total chart_height

```
TOP_AND_BOTTOM_BUFFER = 20
BAR_HEIGHT = 10
GAP_PERCENT = 0.5       ' 50% of the BAR_HEIGHT
chart_height = num_bars * (BAR_HEIGHT + BAR_HEIGHT * GAP_PERCENT) + TOP_AND_BOTTOM_BUFFER
With ActiveChart
    .Parent.Height = chart_height
End With
```

[image: description of the components of the height]

But, I'm getting a non-constant bar height, ***especially when number of bars is 1, the bar is being squished***

***8 element bar chart***
[image: 8 element chart]

***5 element bar chart***
[image: 5 element chart]

And the ***the 1 element chart, where it all went wrong***
[image: 1 element chart]

Comment: Note that there is half a gap width above and below the extreme bars. You may be overstating the top and bottom buffer by this half a gap width.

Comment: I tried to account for the half gapwidth by making the total gapwidth be `n`. We have `(n-1)` in the middle gapwidth and half at both extremes adding `1`. So totally it would be `n` gapwidth

Comment: Does your buffer exclude this half gap width? I thought your sketch showed that it did, which would be wrong. If your buffer is less by a gap width, does it work better?

Comment: You are right, the sketch is poorly drawn. The top and bottom buffer does NOT include the 2 boundary gap width. And I was experimenting with making this `TOP_AND_BOTTOM_BUFFER` be larger and at 43 it seems to be working. I think the problem was I was setting it too low and that was eating into my chart area.